# Solution to a system of symmetric equations: $(x+y)^2 + (x+z)^2 = \frac{2}{3} \lambda x$ etc.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, symmetric-polynomials

After applying the Lagrange multiplier method, I got the following system of equations, which is quite symmetric:

$$(x+y)^2 + (x+z)^2 = \frac{2}{3} \lambda x$$

$$(y+x)^2 + (y+z)^2 = \frac{2}{3} \lambda y $$

$$(z+x)^2 + (z+y)^2 = \frac{2}{3} \lambda z$$

It is claimed that this system of equations is satisfied only when $x=y=z$. Could anyone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, $x=y=z$ leads to the solutions $x = y = z = 0$ and $x = y = z = \frac {\lambda}{12}$. Now, let's assume $x \ne y \ne z$. Subtract second equation from first, third from first and third from second, so you'll get equivalent system
$$
\begin{align}
(x-y)(x+y+2z) &= \frac 23 \lambda (x-y)\\
(x-z)(x+2y+z) &= \frac 23 \lambda (x-z)\\
(y-z)(2x+y+z) &= \frac 23 \lambda (y-z)
\end{align}
$$
or
$$
\begin{align}
x+y+2z &= \frac 23 \lambda\\
x+2y+z &= \frac 23 \lambda\\
2x+y+z &= \frac 23 \lambda
\end{align}
$$
since we assumed that $x \ne y \ne z$.

Comparing first and second, one may conclude that 
$$
x+y+2z = x+2y+z
$$
or equivalently
$$
y = z
$$
Considering other two pairs one may conclude 
$$
x = y = z
$$
which is in contradiction with initial assumptions. So the only solutions are those when $x = y = z$.

### Update

As it was pointed out, one also may check case when $x = y$ but $z \ne x,y$. In this case consider first and third equations
$$
\begin{align}
4x^2 + (x+z)^2 &= \frac 23 \lambda x \\
2(z+x)^2 &= \frac 23 \lambda z
\end{align}
$$
Subtract first from second
$$
(z-x)(z+3x) = \frac 23 \lambda (z-x)
$$
Since we're assuming $z \ne x$, then
$$
z+3x = \frac 23 \lambda
$$
or explicitly
$$
z = \frac 23 \lambda - 3x
$$
Substitute it to the any of previous two, let's say second equation
$$
\left(\frac 23 \lambda - 2x\right)^2 = \frac 13 \lambda \left( \frac 23 \lambda  -3x\right)
$$
and if you solve it, you'll get complex values for $x$. So, contradiction.

In the same manner you can assume $z=y$, $x \ne y,z$ and $z=x$, $y \ne x,z$.

Comment: This does not cover the case that only two out of three are equal (e.g. $x=y$, $z\neq x$, $z \neq y$).

Comment: @WimC you're right, it doesn't. I'll fix it in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

Interpreted as $3$-vectors, the left hand side and the right hand side (without the $\lambda$-factor) must be dependent.  That means that all $2 \times 2$ [minors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_%28linear_algebra%29) of the matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix} (x+y)^2+(x+z)^2 & x\\
(y+x)^2+(y+z)^2 & y\\
(z+x)^2+(z+y)^2 & z
\end{pmatrix}
$$

must vanish (or in other words the cross product of the colums must be zero).  Let's consider the first one:

$$ 0 = y \left( (x+y)^2 + (x+z)^2 \right) - x \left((y+x)^2 + (y+z)^2 \right) = (y-x)(x^2 + xy + y^2 + z^2).
$$

So either $x=y$ or $x^2 + xy + y^2 + z^2 = 0$.  The latter implies that $x=y=z=0$ since the quadratic form is positive definite over $\mathbb{R}$.  In either case $x=y$.  Other equalities follow similarly from the other minors.

One way to show that the quadratic form is positive definite is to write it as a positive combination of squares:

$$x^2 + xy + y^2 + z^2 = \frac{1}{2}\left(x + \frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2} y\right)^2 + \frac{1}{2} \left(x + \frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2} y\right)^2 + z^2$$

Comment: What do you mean by "all 2×2 minors must vanish"? What matrix are you considering?

Comment: @MichaelNgelo Added the matrix explicitly.